# How do I restart my loop from python (arduino-python serial communication)?

Tags: python, loops, arduino, pyserial

I am coding a transporting band using an arduino mega connected to a raspberry with python. When I run this this code (first the arduino one and then the python one) it works once but then, it keeps asking for input but it stops working. I'm asuming it's because it have not ended the loop somehow, maybe is a problem with the communication between arduino and python. Anyone knows what can I do to fix this?

I have tried adding ´exit()´ but I want the code to be in a loop, but when it is repeating itself it stops working.

My code in python is:

```py
import serial, time, sys

ser = serial.Serial('COM1', 9600)
time.sleep(2)

while True:
    print ("Ingrese destino 2, 3 o 4")
    dato = str(input())
    ser.write(dato.encode())
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print ("Ingrese tiempo en segundos de un solo digito")
    dato = str(input())
    ser.write(dato.encode())
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print ("Oprima 1 para comenzar")
    dato = str(input())
    ser.write(dato.encode())
    time.sleep(0.5)
ser.close()
```

My code in arduino:

```
int estado = 0;
int destino;
int inicio;
int tiempo;
int posinicial;
int a=0;
int memoria;
boolean zeta;

unsigned int tiempoActual = 0;
unsigned int tiempoAnterior = 0;
int der = 22; // der en el pin 22
int izq = 23; // izq en el pin 22
int s4 = 37; // s1 en el pin 30
int s3 = 36; // s2 en el pin 31
int s2 = 35; // s3 en el pin 32
int s1 = 34; // s4 en el pin 33

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial3.begin(9600);
pinMode(der, OUTPUT); // configura el der como salida
pinMode(izq, OUTPUT); // configura el izq como salida
pinMode(s1, INPUT); // configura s1 como entrada
pinMode(s2, INPUT); // configura s2 como entrada
pinMode(s3, INPUT); // configura s3 como entrada
pinMode(s4, INPUT); // configura s4 como entrada
Serial3.print("Estado: ");
Serial3.println(estado);
}

void ingreso_datos()
{
Serial3.println("Ingrese destino");
while (Serial.available() == 0)
{
}
destino = Serial.parseInt();
Serial3.println("Ingresetiempo");
while (Serial.available() == 0)
{
}
tiempo = Serial.parseInt();
Serial3.println("Ingrese s para iniciar");
while (Serial.available() == 0)
{
}
inicio = Serial.read();
while (inicio != '1')
{
}
memoria=0;
}

void lectura_sensor(int sensor)
{

switch (sensor){
case 1:
zeta=digitalRead(s1);
break;
case 2:
zeta=digitalRead(s2);
break;
case 3:
zeta=digitalRead(s3);
break;
case 4:
zeta=digitalRead(s4);
break;

}
}

void loop()
{

if(a==0){ingreso_datos();}


if(digitalRead(s1)==HIGH){
estado=1;
} else if(digitalRead(s2)==HIGH){
estado=2;
} else if(digitalRead(s3)==HIGH){
estado=3;
} else if (digitalRead(s4)==HIGH){
estado=4;
} else{estado=estado;}

if(a==0){
posinicial=estado;
a=1; }


if(estado==destino){

digitalWrite(izq,LOW);
digitalWrite(der,LOW);
if(a==1){
delay(tiempo*1000);
memoria=destino;
destino=posinicial;
a=2;
lectura_sensor(memoria);
}else if(a==2 && zeta==0){
a=0;
estado=0;
inicio=0;
tiempo=0;
posinicial=0;
memoria=0;
zeta=0;
}

} else if (estado<destino){

digitalWrite(der,LOW);
digitalWrite(izq,HIGH);

} else if (estado>destino){

digitalWrite(der,HIGH);
digitalWrite(izq,LOW);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it was a ´Serial.flush()´ missing.